# Converted all drawables to WebP, apk size stayed the same

Tags: android, png, webp

Very confused. I just converted a lot of drawables in my res folder to the lossless WebP format. As I did it, Android Studio told me I saved 6mb, however I just build an production-release apk, one for the branch with WebP images and one with everything still as PNG, the difference is negligible. The PNG apk size is 23.2MB, the WebP apk size is 21.3.

I ran the apk analyzer tool, and I can see that the big difference is my res folder is now 7MB smaller, yet that wasn't translated to the apk size?

Here is the apk analyzer results, firstly the old apk (PNGs) Left number is uncompressed, right value is compressed, so what goes out to users in the apk:[image]

Secondly here is the new apk (WebP):
[image]

The drawable files are quite clearly smaller, my biggest folder inside res is now 200kb.

Can someone who has played with WebP in Android offer some information on why this didn't work? No other numbers have changed in the apk analyzer.

Edit: Sorry about the small images, view in new tab to see clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved why it was happened.

I have `shrinkResources` set to `true` on my release builds in my `build.gradle`, so compression was already taking place.

Makes a lot of sense, mistake on my part, totally forgot about it.

Comment: So that means, shrinkResources convert images to webp? Don't think so! If I open my apk (which also was build with `shrinkResources true`), there are still png-files inside the res-directory. So in my opinion you should get an decrease of apk-size, if you use webm format.

Answer (score 0):

You can get better results by using `cwebp -near_lossless 40` for your PNG files. I doubt that the automated shrinkResources is able to use near lossless. This may give another 30-40 % compression gain, depending naturally a lot on what kind of graphics you have.